# Pivot Chart Creation Using Access 2007 VBA

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, pivot

OK there are absolutely no good articles on the internet that I can find that explain or have code examples on how to create a pivot chart using VBA. I need this because I need the pivot chart to show different results depending on user selection in a form. There are some for Excel but the syntax is different for Access. I know this is a lame question, but if anyone has an example of how to create a pivot chart in VBA I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after about 3 days of searching I think I found it. Not that anyone really cares, this only has like 6 views, says a lot for VBA's utter horribleness. Anyway, MSDN had this hidden under "Office XP" instead of under Access, but whatever.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa662945.aspx#

Comment: It only says something about the usability of charts in Access, where there've been major problems integrating MS Graph back as far as 1996 in my experience. Thus, many advanced Access developers avoid it. Pivot tables didn't exist until A2003, & I recall people having problems getting them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a PivotChart form in Access 2007. On another form I have the user selection controls and the pivotform as a subform.  Then I use code like this in the main form.  The object model is the same as OWC11 (Office Web Components 11).

```
Private Function DisplayChart()

  With mysubform.Form.ChartSpace
    .Clear
    .AllowFiltering = True
    .HasChartSpaceTitle = True
    .ChartSpaceTitle.Caption = "test"
    .DisplayFieldButtons = False
    .DisplayToolbar = False

    .ConnectionString = ...
    .CommandText = "SELECT rSeries, rCategory, rDate, rValue " & _
        "FROM myTable"

    .Charts(0).Type = chChartTypePie

    .SetData chDimSeriesNames, chDataBound, "rSeries"
    .SetData chDimCategories, chDataBound, "rCategory"
    .SetData chDimValues, chDataBound, "rValue"

    .HasChartSpaceLegend = True

  End With

End Function
```

the constants can be derived from OWC11

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Components\11\OWC11.DLL

You need them at the top of the module.  At this stage I'm not sure how to extract them from the Access pivotchart.  Make a reference to OWC11 and set the subform ChartSpace to a variable declared as an OWC11.ChartSpace.  After writing the code change to type 'Object', and remove the reference for late binding (and re-test).  This way your refs won't come unstuck on a 64bit machine when you deploy.

```
Private Enum ChartConstants
  chDimSeriesNames = 0
  chDimCategories = 1
  chDimValues = 2
  chDataBound = 0
  chAxisPositionValue = -8
  chAxisPositionCategory = -7
  chChartTypePie = 18
End Enum
```

Remember you can also let the user have access to the PivotChart properties form, field lists and drop zones.  Or they can right-click the chart to get to them.

(Note - this is still a new discovery for me so I will endeavor to update this answer if I find any gotcha's.)

Comment: here's an article by Mike Gunderloy using vba pivotcharts in A2002  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155735%28office.10%29.aspx