# Grouping date values in Office Web Components Chart

Tags: ms-access, vba, charts, office-web-components

How can I format & group dates in the category axes?

I try to do it with this code:

```
With ChartSpace.Charts(0).Axes(chAxisPositionCategory)
    .NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
    .GroupingType = chAxisGroupingManual
End With
```

but all that I get is "invalid parameter".

If I write this:

```
debug.print ChartSpace.Charts(0).Axes(chAxisPositionCategory).NumberFormat
```

I get "General"

and then if I write:

```
ChartSpace.Charts(0).Axes(chAxisPositionCategory).NumberFormat = "General"
```

it's "invalid parameter"!!!

This is VBA code in MS Access using OWC11.  I've bound the data to an SQL Table with 3 columns:

```
Field1 varchar(200),
Date1 datetime, --can't use Date type or the chart won't recognise as date!!
Value1 int
```

I've been searching for help and others have this problem but no one has had an answer - except alternatives that don't fix the problem.  I enve have a MS example that works in html but uses hardcoded data.  I need to use all the time based X axis grouping functions but can't get past a simple number format.

add comment: discovered that this will now work:

```
.Charts(0).Axes(chAxisPositionCategory).CategoryLabels.PivotAxis.Fields(0).NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
```

still can't do the grouping though.

Comment: I doubt that I can help, but I notice that OWC no longer ships with Office (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/excel/archive/2006/07/17/668544.aspx), so it would be as well to include the version of Office that you are using.

Comment: I can't imagine why anybody would want to try to maintain such outdated components that have been deprecated for nearly forever, and never really worked very well even when they were new. Well, other than PHBs.

Comment: @Remou - I'm using a MS Access 2003 ADP connected to a SQL2008 database.

Comment: @David - what's your recommendation for doing charts in MS Access.  I went to Remou's blog link and it sounds like Excel Services is the replacement for OWC.  Any clues on how I would bolt that in to Access 2003? (Maybe I should drop OWC and make this a new question for 'Best charting tool for MS Access?')

Comment: pivotcharts are still available in Access 2007 and 2010.  You can use a pivotchart form without the refs to OWC11 but the object model is not exposed.  So a reference to OWC can used during development.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748274/pivot-chart-creation-using-access-2007-vba/4150480#4150480 .  If PivotCharts are going to be removed from Access in the future then what is the best charting tool for Access now?  If not then when will MS expose the object model?

Comment: What to replace it with depends entirely on what you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but since it is still unanswered and searchable:

You can group by dates in OWC11 by using the timescale option on the x axis:

```
ChartSpace.Charts.Axes[ChartAxisPositionEnum.chAxisPositionTimescale].GroupingType = ChartAxisGroupingEnum.chAxisGroupingNone;
```

The default behavior is to group the dates, use the GroupingNone enum to turn that off.

@David-W-Fenton: OWC11 is depreceated but is in extended support until 2014 and still downloadable. There has never been a MS replacement for them that has all the functionality. The chart controls for .NET 3.5 don't allow the end user to manipulate the chart in the same way. I would not use OWC in a website due to security issues, but I use them in internal WinForms apps. I don't know of another free chart control that allows the same level of runtime chart manipulation as OWC. (Sorry for adding a comment to an answer but I don't have the priviledge to comment yet).